# Firebase query not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase structure like below.

[image]

All I want is those data whose "coach_user_id" I will pass.

My code is like below.

```
let ref1 = self.dbRef.child(activity).queryOrdered(byChild: "coach_user_id")
        ref1.queryEqual(toValue: "33", childKey: "coach_user_id").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot :FIRDataSnapshot?) in
            if let values : Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = snapshot?.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            {

            }
        }
```

PS: We did not apply any rules in firebase, I don't know if it is compulsory or not.

Comment: What's your path for the 'activity' variable you're referencing in child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `queryOrderedByChild`

```
let ref = self.dbRef.child("activity")

ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "coach_user_id").queryEqual(toValue: "33").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in 
    if let activity = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] { 
        // do stuff with 'activity' here.
    } 
})
```